# How to create formula in excel that can iterate in specific range?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to fill down 10 cells with value from B10 cell: ='Disconnect Minor Reason List'!$B$10, then I want to get another 10 cells with value from B11 cell, then another 10 from B12 and so on. Is it a possible in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's any way you can add the row number (10 times 10, followed by 10 times 11 and so on), you can use `=INDIRECT("B" & rowNumber)`.

You could also try `OFFSET`.